# How to combine, organize types to merge similar functions into one generic function

Tags: typescript

I have these types and these functions:

```
type Maybe<A> = A | undefined

type HeadlineSequence = ["text", "headline", "text"]
type HeadlineSelect = "headline"

type ContentSequence = ["content", "headline"]
type ContentSelect = "content"


function sequenceHeadline(ss: HeadlineSequence,
    fA: (_: Array<string>) => HeadlineSelect): Maybe<HeadlineSelect> {

   let accs: Array[string] = [];

   for (let _matcher of ss) {
       let _res = _matcher;
       if (!_res) {
           return undefined;
       }

       accs.push(_acc);
   }

   return fA(accs);
}

function sequenceContent(ss: ContentSequence,
    fA: (_: Array<string>) => ContentSelect): Maybe<ContentSelect> {

   let accs: Array[string] = [];

   for (let _matcher of ss) {
       let _res = _matcher;
       if (!_res) {
           return undefined;
       }

       accs.push(_acc);
   }

   return fA(accs);
}
```

The function accumulates a result on `HeadlineSequence` then reduces that result into a type of `HeadlineSelect` type.

Two functions basically do the same thing except the types differ.

How can I capture this with a single function, I've tried defining additional types, but I don't know how to use these types.

```
type Sequencable = [HeadlineSequence, HeadlineSelect] |
    [ContentSequence, ContentSelect]
```

Comment: I think you want a function overload: // https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads
 (I think this is likely a duplicate of an existing question somewhere)

Comment: No I want to define a new function that works for both types, and delete these two functions. Because they are basically the same, except the types differ.

Comment: Yup! You want a single function with function overloads for the types. You can sometimes accomplish the same thing with generic types and `extends`, but I find function overload types to be more clear, easier to implement, and more powerful

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so as to constitute a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue and only your issue when dropped into a standalone IDE.  [Currently](https://tsplay.dev/Nn64xN) there are a few typos and a missing `_acc` reference; it would be nice to dispense with those apparently irrelevant problems while answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could represent both `sequenceHeadline` and `sequenceContent` as special cases of the following generic function:

```
function sequenceUnconstrained<SQ extends string[], SS extends string>(ss: SQ,
    fA: (_: Array<string>) => SS): Maybe<SS> {
    let accs: Array<string> = [];
    for (let _matcher of ss) {
        let _res = _matcher;
        if (!_res) {
            return undefined;
        }
        accs.push(_acc);
    }
    return fA(accs);
}
```

This should accept anything `sequenceHeadline` or `sequenceContent` accepts:

```
sequenceUnconstrained(["text", "headline", "text"], v => "headline"); // okay
sequenceUnconstrained(["content", "headline"], v => "content") // okay
```

but it also accepts other possible arrays of string inputs and string outputs:

```
sequenceUnconstrained(["foo", "bee", "doo"], v => "123"); // no error
```

If that's not important, then we're done.

---

If you really do want to constrain it to be exactly either of the two versions and make use of your `Sequencable` type

```
type Sequencable = [HeadlineSequence, HeadlineSelect]
    | [ContentSequence, ContentSelect];
```

Then you can change the call signature to this:

```
type Select<S extends Sequencable[0]> = Extract<Sequencable, [S, any]>[1];

function sequence<S extends Sequencable[0], NH extends string>(ss: S,
    fA: (_: Array<string>) => NH & Select<S>): Maybe<Select<S>> {
    // same impl
}
```

Ignoring the `NH` for now, we are [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `S`, the type of `ss`, to extend the first element of `Sequencable` (which will be the union `HeadlineSequence | ContentSequence`).  And then for the return type of `fA` and the function itself, we are evaluating `Select<S>` by [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)ing the member of `Sequencable` whose first element is `S`, and then returning the second element of that member.  So `Select<HeadlineSequence>` is `HeadlineSelect`, and `Select<ContentSequence>` is `ContentSelect`.

The `NH` bit is just a little annoying thing to give the compiler a hint that it should be trying to infer the return type of `fA` as a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) instead of just `string`.  For whatever reason, if I leave this off, then `v => "headline"` will be inferred as type `(_: Array<string>) => string` instead of `(_: Array<string>) => "headline"`.  By explicitly adding a generic type parameter which includes `string` and intersecting it with the expected return type, the compiler gets the hint.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a feature request to support some less weird way to hint that call signatures should infer literal types.

Anyway, let's test it out:

```
sequence(["text", "headline", "text"], v => "headline"); // okay
sequence(["content", "headline"], v => "content") // okay
sequence(["foo", "bee"], v => "123"); // error! '"foo"' is not assignable to '"content" | "text"
sequence(["text", "headline", "text"], v => "123"); // error! string is not never
```

Looks good; the acceptable calls are the ones that work for your two original functions, and the unacceptable calls are ones that do not.

---

Just to be sure, we can make sure that the compiler sees `sequence` as being assignable to the types of your two original functions:

```
const sH: typeof sequenceHeadline = sequence; // okay
const sC: typeof sequenceContent = sequence; // okay
```

The fact that this works means that you should be able to use `sequence` as you would use  `sequenceHeadline` and also as you would use `sequenceContent`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAQQHxQLxTVAHygFcA7AEwgDMBLUicgWACgXRIoAJCOcgGzoQAyhACOxCKQDG0XAG0ARMAgAPYAoA0UBQAse-QZu3K1CgLptw0brwH0RfCFOA5te24ZaWOAYQD2pMqBIuKSMq6KUgFB6lq6+nYQ5t7Q-oGSwA5OLrgKUemBCl7M+QDOLgD6cFJSrgoA7jp+ANKkfvWlCgDcxcVUZM40AVClYhLSEACq0gHlAE5wguQoQgCKUKpB5KUjwHN0AOZyZlpCQhtqktu7+6QHGAAUpaUAXFBrGixQ31BUaG8PCpvNBzBYgFDzQ4YACUOCwZ2hb3gSFQZywAG8vj9HC5qlJXnhQQgIXsoREzD1mD9fn45lAHjioBUALZwYBSPR0vxUEalWGYqnU7EQSpzCA7XAstkciBzSlCn40HkPACEFTFfKgAoVCrFwGIc1IJAo1CW8p1AF8sQq8aUAHRgYilHSAvHQ83fK2C756g1Gv4PW3ulhelijUITaZlPaLejkB6KEyxNwJQxxJPmLQANzhKY89AU7qgAHpi1A-ABrBBhsZhKYzUjzWMMBN5aIZIzxfNJE5QHPYLBtgrqWGl8tVkA1iMyKOzGNLVtUPx+TvIJJxcjLzN93MKACMACYAMyFrolsttDag2nFdjQELjKRwRCOCI2Az2WsTLTvxJZZwWN6hBQHIaQxA+dZaGBGT-sAFK3lY7wQI4zgrBcWw7BB0jPo4cgAAxmFguAAKJqAsqFYU+L4QFochCFocCkCAhFyHu8GsMw-TSMAQxGuGj6ouhVyYV+VG4QRWgAHKcEJFA7JCdyPM8bz0davz-PSQKEmCJK3PcsIDlA0lQAAZEhKHACsMJIggyArMh2RWRixTUoytrAkS4IKfc5KUmpS50gyIpMqy7KcuWPLPPyamucF6riq4UphbKHpCkq9Jqhq0VATqUC+oaxqULQcapdSoY5T8toOk6LpVDUwZAeV1L5f6aCBjUfKUuV-F1q2GZxO4H7rsYmzbv2g6DYkp7nuO1bMD1EytvkMSdpNhi9uN2jLR2o5lpWc0LTIi5bnEa6dpuK4bbuh4nkWY6ynMtIqlAAAqiEAOQKEuK7vVANA7G0uLPDQBykDh0DAH4UB3lAn3bYUwFKKNU4CX1o0DamBbpqNV2Gfux7Tfd15zM93l-QDfguPQWaysU0YjJwbx3tyIyiRAv6CK4h0QGeY77ZOJRziMPhM1YLPc9BgRc2zvN7ROvScQMPHDNzHP0E8BJq8IbOfEBfwAlpII6d5MK5lrsGIrAtmoObDnOM5HGxbiHUecbpKKb5Lk-AF9KMklMpcpFmrajqfsaoloUB6VirKpl4rZblzUin6hWmiVMU-E1OpVY6zquvVqVZz6ycFQGQZdX0Su8az04QJLwAa289eUTR-kaYCrvEibBlYM3dvAJbyJ2X3FkO2pbku9pXfuz58jsf5tK+3FkfheLwcZ98YcJZKK8pRvf2x-F68VbqJdGmQRVmvvRdCjnNX51IDVlV7xf6qXbXlyGLBAA)